# Using Node.js w/ Cheerio to pre-process HTML

Tags: jquery, node.js, cheerio

I have the unfortunate task of converting a significant amount of HTML pages over to a new template.  I will need to port the  and place it into the new template's , plus some additional DOM manipulation.  Unfortunately, these need to be hosted as static HTML pages.

I'm wondering if Node.js with Cheerio running jQuery would be appropriate or is there another method that I should consider.

Comment: I think you can scratch `jquery` out of the list of tags. If you own the pages and have them available in the form of files (no scrapping needed) then `node.js` + `cheerio` are good tools

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cheerio` works pretty well for most use cases.  `jsdom` might be needed for some more complex ones, but  it has significantly worse performance so only use it if `cheerio` doesn't work.

Comment: Cheerio is working great!  I still have to cobble the full application together so I'm not sure if I'll hit a wall in functionality, but I can see this being very useful.